# Error while installing JDeveloper 12c 12.2.1.4

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, jdeveloper, oracle12.2

I want to install Oracle JDeveloper 12c (12.2.1.4.0) Studio Edition. But I am facing some problem. I can't install the software. I have tried the Generic Version, windows 64bit as well as 32bit. But all the time same issue.
But when I install the Oracle JDeveloper 12c (12.2.1.3.0) Studio Edition, there is no problem at all. But my company use 12.2.1.4.0 .

I download the file from : https://www.oracle.com/in/tools/downloads/jdeveloper-12c-downloads.html#

then I create a folder in C:\Extra_Oracle_Softwares\JDeveloper122140
extract the file.
And run the exe file "Run as Administrator"

In the same way I have tried the older version. It worked. But specifically this version showing me error.

Launcher log file is C:\Users\Rahat10101\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2022-09-19_02-12-10PM\launcher2022-09-19_02-12-10PM.log.

Extracting the installer . . . . Done

Self extraction to C:\Users\Rahat10101\AppData\Local\Temp\sfx8FE0.tmp failed.

The log is located here: C:\Users\Rahat10101\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2022-09-19_02-12-10PM\launcher2022-09-19_02-12-10PM.log.

Press Enter to exit

How can I solve this problem ? I am trying this for the last 7 days.

Comment: please try to write the log instead of taking pictures

Comment: The error message refers to a logfile. Did you look in that logfile? Maybe there are clues about what's wrong in there.

Answer (score 1):

Steps :
Download V998594-01.zip and V998593-01.exe
Rename the V998594-01.zip to V998593-01-2.zip
Run V998593-01.exe as Administrator

Comment: Worked. The log tells you exactly what files it needs. Oracle this is a very stupid mistake.